# How to call socket module properly in Python

Tags: python, udp, udpclient

I am building a simple UDP client, however, I am getting an error message "socket is not callable". I have checked the code and it can find the problem

I tried importing the module by using "from socket import *" but it didn't work.

```
import socket
serverName = 'hostname'
serverPort = 1200
clientSocket = socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
message = 'Testing the system'
clientSocket.sendto(message, (serverName, serverPort))
modifiedMessage, serverAddress = clientSocket.recvfrom(2048)
print(modifiedMessage)
clientSocket.close()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to import socket from socket module like this

```
import socket
from socket import socket as sk
serverName = 'hostname'
serverPort = 1200
clientSocket = sk(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
```

etc

Answer (score 0):

I think you have named your program as `socket.py` or stored your program in a folder that contains `socket.py` . Either rename your file or delete them

Answer (score 0):

Your code should work, you just need to change

```
clientSocket = socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
```

To

```
clientSocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
```

You are trying to feed inputs to a module (`socket`) instead of the function inside the module (`socket.socket`)